# Add comment boxes to all options for user flags

Tags: feature-request, flags

Currently when flagging posts I can either choose one of the predefined options, or the "Other" option. However, only the option "It needs moderator attention" and suboption "Other" have a way for me to actually comment on the flag. It would be good if I could add a comment to any flag, so that unusual circumstances are more clearly stated.

Comment: Why does the current option not suffice?

Comment: It feels wrong to disregard the ability to say "This post is off-topic" just so that I can say "This post is off-topic because...".

Comment: And then, let's allow flagging _those_ comments ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When flagging a post or comment, provide a freeform text entry field for all reasons, not just "other"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301835/when-flagging-a-post-or-comment-provide-a-freeform-text-entry-field-for-all-rea) - that's significantly newer but also contains more reasons why this is a good idea.